# PHP called by Javascript is outputting everything immediately

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a working PHP script that takes a while to load, and during the loading time I am outputting some content via `echo` and `flush()`. Everything works fine but now I want to call the script using Javascript/jQuery because of some design issues.

If I call my PHP script when pressing a button it loads everything directly without waiting for certain steps to finish in the script. It's like my exec command is being processed in the background, as if I was using `> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` at the end of my exec which I am not.

I thought of  putting the PHP script in the same index.PHP and call it from there.

Note: It is important that the PHP script is either in another file or can be placed at the bottom of the file which contains HTML.

Javascript:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#download-mp3").click(function(){
            $("#div1").load("php/download.php", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                if(statusTxt == "success")
                    alert("External content loaded successfully!");
                if(statusTxt == "error")
                    alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
  echo '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Starting to gather data!</li>';
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  $url = $unsplash;
  $cmd = $unsplash . ' - ' . $amount;
  exec($cmd);
  echo '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Gathering Data Completed</li>';
  ob_end_flush();
 exec(command for downloading data);
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, can you show the relevant lines of codes?

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I edited my answer, Sorry :)

Comment: [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) waits for the HTML to download before appending it to the HTML element. If you want to do something like that, you'll need to look at something like Web Sockets or server-side push.